# Cocoa Pod unable to find specifications for

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoapods

here is my pod file

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘8.0‘
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'LIDO' do

pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.0.0'
pod 'AEXML'
#pod 'SwiftyButton'
pod 'ActionButton'
pod 'DOFavoriteButton'
#pod "VideoSplash"
pod 'LNRSimpleNotifications', '0.2.0'
pod 'EZLoadingActivity'
#pod 'SwiftOverlays', '~> 1.0'
pod 'PureLayout'
end
```

but for

pod 'SwiftyButton'
pod "VideoSplash"
pod 'SwiftOverlays', '~> 1.0'

i always run into a

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `<name>`

any idea why? 
i can find all these

http://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyButton
http://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftOverlays
http://cocoapods.org/pods/VIDEOSPLASH

and it did work until yesterday?

Comment: You project is an objective c or swift project?

Comment: did you update cocoapods to latest version? i had the same problem just run the "sudo gem install cocoapods"

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to execute `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master` because it'll remove all the bogus and corrupted repos that you have in your computer to give it a chance to repopulate after you redo `pod setup`, which'll reinstate you with a fresh Cocoapods setup. Additionally, you'll want to specify `sudo xcode-select --switch /applications/Xcode.app` where your new version of Xcode is. That was just another setup procedure that I had to do to complete the fix. From there, just do `pod setup` and you're set to run `pod install` to integrate all the libraries that you want!